# ¿Por qué no detecta el evento de clic? jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Estoy creando un blog de noticias, en la página de inicio se muestran las entradas del blog y en cada entrada tengo unos botones que aparecen al pasar el mouse sobre alguna entrada, en estos botones puedes editar, eliminar o archivar (pausar) la entrada. Mi problema es que cuando doy clic al botón de archivar (pausar) o eliminar, no hace nada, no detecta el clic.

Las entradas se muestran de la siguiente manera mediante el uso de una paginación:

**Archivo index.php**

```
···
<section class="catBlog relativo">
  <section class="catDesp" id="catDesp2">
    <a href="javascript:paginacion(1,'blog')" class="secCat" id="blg_btn">Blog</a>
    <a href="javascript:paginacion(1,'noticias')" class="secCat" id="ntc_btn">Noticias</a>
    <a href="javascript:paginacion(1,'eventos')" class="secCat" id="evt_btn">Eventos</a>
  </section>

  <div class="entradaDesp2">
    <span id="entradas">
      <?php include_once 'includes/funciones/paginacion.php'; ?>
    </span>
  </div>

</section>
···
```

Esto carga las entradas desde este archivo:

**Archivo paginacion.php**

```
  ···
  try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sentencia);
    if ($cargo == 'admin') {
      $stmt->bind_param('s',$tipo_entrada);
    } else {
      $stmt->bind_param('sss',$tipo_entrada,$cargo,$usuario);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    $elementos = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($ele = $elementos->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      foreach ($ele as $artBajo) { ?>
        <section class="articulosBajos clearfix relativo animated fadeInUp" id="artIndex">
          <article class="articulo"><?php
            if ($artBajo["estado"] == "pausa") { ?>
              <div class="triangulo"></div><?php
            } ?>
            <img src="../img/imagen.jpg" alt="">
            <h2><?php echo $artBajo["titulo"] ?></h2>
            <p class="alto"><?php echo $artBajo["descripcion"] ?>...</p>
            <?php $id_blog = $artBajo["id_entrada"] ?>
          </article>
          <div class="contBtnIndex_pb btnIndex" data-id="<?=$id_blog?>" id="blg">
            <!-- EDITAR -->
            <a href="editar.php?entr=<?=$tipo?>&id=<?=$id_blog?>" style="display:flex;" class="btnIndex_pb edit">
              <i class="btn_act">/</i>
              <p class="btn_name">editar</p>
            </a> <!-- EDITAR --> <?php
            if ($artBajo["estado"] == "pausa") { ?>
            <!-- DESACTIVAR PAUSA -->
              <div style="display:flex;" class="btnIndex_pb pausa_inac">
                <input type="button" id="pausa_inac" class="btn_act" value="d">
                <label for="pausa_inac" class="btn_name">desarchivar</label>
              </div> <!-- DESCACTIVAR PAUSA --><?php
            } else { ?>
            <!-- ACTIVAR PAUSA -->
            <div style="display:flex;" class="btnIndex_pb pausa">
              <input type="button" id="pausar"  class="btn_act" value="a">
              <label for="pausa" class="btn_name">archivar</label>
            </div> <!-- ACTIVAR PAUSA --> <?php
            } ?>
            <div style="display:flex;" class="btnIndex_pb eliminar">
              <input type="button" id="eliminar"  class="btn_act" value="x" data-id="blg" id="<?=$id_blog?>">
              <label for="eliminar" class="btn_name">eliminar</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section> <?php
      //Final articulo
      }
    } $stmt->close();
  } catch (exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    $stmt->close();
  }
  // Final articulo
```

Y con *jquery* hago el llamado a *ajax* (pongo el evento de archivar solamente para ahorrar código, ya que para eliminar se usaría el mismo método):

**Archivo main.js**
(Las variables están creadas previamente al comienzo del archivo)

```
    ···
    //Ajax pausar----------------------------------------
    $('#entradas').on('click','.articulosBajos .btnIndex .pausa',function(){
        parametros = {
            "pausar": this.find('.pausa').val(),
            "id": this.parents('div').attr('data-id'),
            "entr": this.parents('div').attr('id')
        }
        triangulo = $(this).parents('section').children('article');
        btn = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('pausar');
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/funciones/pausar.php',
            data: parametros
        }).done(function(response) {
            // $(".resultado").html(response);
            triangulo.prepend('<div class="triangulo"></div>');
            btn.prev('a').after('<input type="button" class="btnIndex_pb pausa_inac" value="d">');
            btn.remove();
        });
    });

    $('#entradas').on('click','.btnIndex .pausa_inac',function(e){
        parametros = {
            "pausar_inac": this.val(),
            "id_inac": this.parents('div').attr('data-id'),
            "entr_inac": this.parents('div').attr('id')
        }
        triangulo = $(this).parents('section').children('article').children('div');
        btn = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('despausar');
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/funciones/pausar.php',
            data: parametros
        }).done(function() {
            // $(".resultado").html(response);
            triangulo.remove();
            btn.prev('a').after('<input type="button" class="btnIndex_pb pausa" value="p">');
            btn.remove();
        });
    });
```

Tengo entendido que cuando se cargan elementos de forma dinámica, hay que buscar dicho elemento desde su selector de origen, en este caso lo busco desde `$('#entradas')` y le paso los selectores hijo hasta llegar al selector que quiero: `$('#entradas').on('click','.articulosBajos .btnIndex .pausa',function()`

Según lo que he aprendido debería funcionar, pero no es el caso.   ¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Comment: Cuando un elemento tiene dos clases `class="btnIndex_pb pausa"` no se deben incluir espacios en el selector: `$('#entradas').on('click','. articulosBajos .btnIndex.pausa', function() {});` La clase `.articulosBajos` sí se separa porque es el contenedor.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, lamentablemente sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Sí, me sobró un espacio en `. articulosBajos`, no sé de dónde salió, debería ser `.articulosBajos`

Comment: Yo lo corregí, lo puse tal cual va, pero sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Cuando un elemento tiene dos clases `class="btnIndex_pb pausa"` no se deben incluir espacios en el selector: `$('#entradas').on('click','. articulosBajos .btnIndex_pb.pausa', function() {});` La clase `.articulosBajos` sí se separa porque es el contenedor.

Adicionalmente, te recomiendo algunos cambios para generar un HTML correcto y simplificar la forma en que asignas eventos:

- No repitas ID, estos [deben ser únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), siempre que necesites asignar ID en ciclos, agrega un sufijo, que puede ser ID del artículo: `id="artIndex-<?=$id_blog?>"`. Debes hacerlo también con los enlaces, botones y en el `for` de las etiquetas (`<label>`).
- Solo al contenedor de cada artículo asigna atributo de datos `<section class="articulosBajos clearfix relativo animated fadeInUp" id="artIndex-<?=$id_blog?>" data-id="<?=$id_blog?>">`
- Asigna los eventos directamente a enlaces o botones y accede por la clase que tienen estos elementos, no su contenedor
- Cuando se haga clic en alguno de los enlaces o botones, puedes obtener el padre y buscar el atributo de datos `data-id` en caso de necesitarlo

Revisa el HTML para ver lo que debes corregir (ID, clases, `for` de etiquetas, etc.).

```js
// Enlace para editar: .edit es la clase del enlace
$('#entradas').on('click', '.articulosBajos .edit', function(e) {
    // Cancelar comportamiento normal de evento
    e.preventDefault();
    // $(this) es el enlace
    console.log($(this)[0]);
    // Obtener ID desde elemento padre (section)
    console.log($(this).closest('section').data('id'));
});

// Para desactivar: .pausa_inac es el contenedor, .btn_act es la clase del botón
$('#entradas').on('click', '.articulosBajos .pausa_inac .btn_act', function(e) {
    // Cancelar comportamiento normal de evento
    e.preventDefault();
    // $(this) es el botón
    console.log($(this)[0]);
});

// Para activar: .pausa es el contenedor, .btn_act es la clase del botón
$('#entradas').on('click', '.articulosBajos .pausa .btn_act', function(e) {
    // Cancelar comportamiento normal de evento
    e.preventDefault();
    // $(this) es el botón
    console.log($(this)[0]);
});

// Para eliminar: .eliminar es el contenedor, .btn_act es la clase del botón
$('#entradas').on('click', '.articulosBajos .eliminar .btn_act', function(e) {
    // Cancelar comportamiento normal de evento
    e.preventDefault();
    // $(this) es el botón
    console.log($(this)[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="entradas">
    <section class="articulosBajos clearfix relativo animated fadeInUp" id="artIndex-1" data-id="1">
          <article class="articulo">
              <div class="triangulo"></div>
            <img src="../img/imagen.jpg" alt="">
            <h2>Título</h2>
            <p class="alto">Descripción...</p>
          </article>
          <div class="contBtnIndex_pb btnIndex" id="blg-1">
            <!-- EDITAR -->
            <a href="editar.php?entr=1" style="display:flex;" class="btnIndex_pb edit">
              <i class="btn_act">/</i>
              <p class="btn_name">editar</p>
            </a> <!-- EDITAR -->
            <!-- DESACTIVAR PAUSA -->
              <div style="display:flex;" class="btnIndex_pb pausa_inac">
                <input type="button" id="pausa_inac-1" class="btn_act" value="d">
                <label for="pausa_inac-1" class="btn_name">desactivar</label>
              </div> <!-- DESCACTIVAR PAUSA -->
            <!-- ACTIVAR PAUSA -->
            <div style="display:flex;" class="btnIndex_pb pausa">
              <input type="button" id="pausar-1" class="btn_act" value="a">
              <label for="pausar-1" class="btn_name">activar</label>
            </div> <!-- ACTIVAR PAUSA -->
            <div style="display:flex;" class="btnIndex_pb eliminar">
              <input type="button" id="eliminar-1"  class="btn_act" value="x" id="eliminar-1">
              <label for="eliminar-1" class="btn_name">eliminar</label>
            </div>
          </div>
    </section>
</div>
```